Package 'libpng12-dev' won't install? Trying to setup OpenCV for object detection
I'm trying to setup OpenCV for object detection on my Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I'm using the 32-bit Legacy OS, as it's recommended for this application.
When running the command
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev

the terminal installs the first three packages without a problem, and then I get an error message for libpng12-dev, saying
E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate


Use libpng-dev instead of libpng12-dev, as the latter has been deprecated.
Your command becomes
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng-dev

See also E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate
